# How do I abbreviate a branch name in a git pull request?

Tags: git, pull

The command I want to run is

```
git pull origin_au a_really_long_branch_name_that_i_dont_want_to_type
```

Is there anyway I can abbreviate the branch name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply use the Tab key to auto complete that long branch name.

If not, be sure to set up auto-completion with the help of the following files: https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion

Which ones you need depend on the shell you use, for bash, it is `git-completion.bash`. Just put the file in a folder that is in your path variable and you should be good.

See [this thread on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/31744/how-to-get-git-completion-bash-to-work-on-mac-os-x) for more info. Some additional info is also available on [the githib page of git flow](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion).

Comment: What's your environment? Windows, Linux? Which shell are you using?

Comment: Im using a mac and bash shell.

Comment: That worked.  I downloaded https://github.com/git/git/raw/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash saved it to ~/.git-completion.sh and added source ~/.git-completion.sh to ~/.bash_profile.